# Match all values in a join view table

Tags: mysql, join, view, having

I have the following code where I create a view from two tables. I select few columns from each table. I tried to get the values from `inventory.location_x` and `inventory.location_y`from all the matches from both tables. However, it only selects one. It should return at least 3 pars of values.

Somebody can help me?

```
CREATE VIEW summary AS ( 
    SELECT contexts, description, SKU, inventory.location_x, inventory.location_y    
    FROM inventory 
    LEFT JOIN product on inventory.epc_hex = product.epc having max(inventory.cycle)
);
```

Here there is a link to find an example of the two tables and the desired output:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k2imnxkqu412mp3/AABeIjgPUflPm8yx9nvr_uida?dl=0

Comment: You might want to add some sample data, table structure and desired/expected output to your question (you can use the edit feature); without that information it's a bit hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you are using the "having" clause without specifying any aggregate functions in the select part of the sql.

Try removing the having clause and you will get more records. Try the following:

```
CREATE VIEW summary AS ( 
    SELECT contexts, description, SKU, inventory.location_x, inventory.location_y    
FROM inventory 
LEFT JOIN product on inventory.epc_hex = product.epc
);
```

The following webpage gives examples on how to use the having clause: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: There are several problems with his SQL.  Rather than linking to an outside resource (especially [one known for its inaccuracies](http://www.w3fools.com/)), consider demonstrating the solution with code of your own.

Comment: Thanks Abraham B. I've tried this query without havind and it does provide more records, but a lot more. I would like to get only the last records for each sample of the product table which matches with the equal condition. Could you provide me an example? Raúl